# c3chart export issues - styles are not downloaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, c3.js

Is there a way to export svg generated by c3 chart with the styles. I am able to export the svg to png image but the styles are missing. I am using c3 angular to generate charts.

Answer (score 0):

When you export chart , only svg part is exported with its inline styles . To export svg with its css you need to add the styles in the svg tag itself .

for ex :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
            circle {
                stroke: #909;
                stroke-width: 10;
                fill: #f6f;
            }
        ]]></style>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="80" />
</svg>
```

Add your styles to svg like this then export it as svg or png .

Comment: I am not generating the svg. It is generated by the c3chart so it will be hard to add inline styles.

Comment: you can add styles like this  : $('svg defs').prepend('<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[     .c3-ygrid-line line {   stroke: red !important; }]]></style> ')

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a while, I found a solution to export svg with styles by gonsakon. It can be found in the below link 
https://github.com/gonsakon/SVGtoPNG